# How to understand this phrase?

Tags: grammar

> **ゲームの歴史**それははるか**5,000年の昔古代エジプト**にまで**さかのぼる**という｡

Well, I can understand some parts of it (which I put in bold):

- ゲームの歴史: game history.
- 5,000年の昔: 5000 years ago.
- 古代エジプト: ancient Egypt.
- さかのぼる: go up.

But the meaning of it seems unreachable to me. :(
I've researched in websites like: jgram, imabi, renshuu.org. But I haven't had luck. It feels like the structures I do study are never seen in authentic language use, hahaha.
This text is the opening of the first Yu-Gi-Oh episode.

Could somebody help me make sense of the elements of this sentence?

Comment: Actually I can get the meaning, I guess. But some elements are unrecognizable to me. Why is it SO hard to research some Japanese grammar? O_o

Comment: You can try looking at [our resources page](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) for other sites that may help in your search.

Answer (score 7):

> ゲームの歴史、それははるか5,000年の昔、古代エジプトにまでさかのぼるという｡

"The history of games goes way back to ancient Egypt about 5000 years ago."

Something about this sentence feels a bit clipped to me.  But nevertheless, "さかのぼる" is a great word that more or less means to go upstream, against the flow of the river.  But in this context, its meaning is to reach back, figuratively, in time.

はるか gives the sense of being quite a ways away.  (After all, 5000 years is almost all of recorded history, so pretty far back.)

にまで is another nice construct combining the two particles に (at) and まで (upto) which in this context means "back to".

Comment: If you could explain why the downvote, then I might know how to write a better answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I can only guess.  Maybe it's because your gloss for まで is 'from'?

Comment: @snailboat Argh.  You're right.  Mind one place, fingers some where else.  Sigh.

Comment: I think it's 'the history of games'; but you couldn't tell easily without context. (I think I've read the manga this is from.)

Comment: @Sjiveru Agreed. If you're going to talk about a game you've already mentioned, you won't start with ゲームの歴史、それは…

Comment: Wow, much clearer now! Thanks!
Only, do you happen to know the use of the "それは" and "という". I know how to use them in other situations, but they don't seem to fit in such phrase. I thought maybe the "という" meant "It's said", but I coudn't find support for such guess. I have a collection of dictionaries, but I coudn't find a proper meaning. Nor on the web.

Comment: @GabrielMorato 1) The それ refers to ゲームの歴史, and「ゲームの歴史は、はるか5000年前…」 would mean the same thing, but here it's written that way for a stylistic/rhetorical effect. For more about the usage of 「noun, それは～～」, you can see [this thread](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9406/how-to-make-sense-of-this-construct-%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E-%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AF%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E%E5%8F%A5).  2) The という at the end means "They say ~~" or "It is said that~~". It means almost the same as 「と言われている。」 (The と is a quotative particle, and the いう is the verb 言う.)